# how to keep variables and sprite kit scene in view controller

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, viewcontroller

I'm trying to make app with slide menu to switch between view controllers .
Opening of the view controller is done by this code :

```
let destViewController : UIViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: strIdentifier)
let topViewController : UIViewController = self.navigationController!.topViewController!

if (topViewController.restorationIdentifier! == destViewController.restorationIdentifier!) {
  print("Same VC")
} else {
 self.navigationController!.pushViewController(destViewController, animated: true)
}
```

one of the view controllers contains SKview with skscene presented. However, when I open this view controller after switching to another , the sprite kit scene is not shown (the sound in it continues to play), so that it creates another skscene. 
Is there any way to keep all variables/spritekit scenes during switching between view controllers ?

Comment: your problem is you are most likely using the viewdidload to create the scene,  move it somewhere else, and only present during viewdidload

Comment: the scene is not created in viewdidload, there is a separate function , which is creating one when being called. The problem is , that when the viewcontroller is presented, it "doesn't know" anything about scenes created before (and they are not deleted, the sound is still playing), and there is no way to access them.